# Error when trying to run CDK test: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON, starting at object with constructor 'CloudFormationStackArtifact'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, ts-jest

I'm new to CDK, I wrote my CDK and it's deployed and everything works fine and as expected, now comes the fun part to write tests for my CDK.

This is my CDK file (rte-stack.ts):

```js
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
export class RTEStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Read from secrets manager role
    const lambdaReadFromASMRole = new iam.Role(this, 'lambdaReadFromASMRole', {
      roleName: 'lambdaReadFromASMRole',
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("SecretsManagerReadWrite"),
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

I wrote a simple test:

```js
import * as assert from '@aws-cdk/assert';
import { SynthUtils } from '@aws-cdk/assert';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as RTE from '../lib/rte-stack';

const { expect: expectCDK, haveResource } = assert;

test('Stack creates resources', () => {
    const app = new cdk.App();
    const stack = new RTE.RTEStack(app, 'MyTestStack', {
        env: {
            account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
            region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION
        }
    });

    expectCDK(stack).to(assert.countResources('AWS::IAM::Role', 1));
});
```

But when I try to run my test I get:

```
  ● Stack creates resources

    TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
        --> starting at object with constructor 'CloudFormationStackArtifact'
        |     property 'assembly' -> object with constructor 'CloudAssembly'
        |     property 'artifacts' -> object with constructor 'Array'
        --- index 0 closes the circle
        at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

This is the versions I'm using in the package.js

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "1.125.0",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "jest": "27.0.5",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "aws-cdk": "1.125.0",
    "ts-node": "9.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "1.125.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2": "1.125.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "1.125.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs": "1.125.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-rds": "1.125.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.125.0",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.20"
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue as well, when using a custom construct. It looks like you also have a custom construct called `RTEStack`.

In my case, my custom construct turned out to have a dependency of CDK v1.124.0, and the project where I was writing the test that used the custom construct had a dependency on v1.125.0. The issue was resolved by making sure they used the same version of CDK (I updated both to 1.127.0 in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same, removing `^` before version of all CDK libs helped, but its already not your case as I see